# fetch() fails in Chrome extension under Windows but not MacOS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

**Introduction (added in edit)**:I am working on a Chrome extension that I want to be able to communicate with a server using `fetch()`. When I included such a feature in the new version of the extension, I noticed that only a very small fraction of the users recorded by the Chrome Web Store stats actually had made contact with the server, although that should happen automatically when the extension loads (my server script logs the requests). Therefore there seems to be some difference between different instances of the extension, maybe due to different OSes, in the capacity to perform the `fetch()` command.

**Question:**  I have created a minimalistic demo extension below which contains the `fetch()` step. Basically, the server returns the date and time in PHP "U" format (seconds since Jan 1, 1970) and the extension then logs this data to the console. Using this on the Mac on which I developed the extension, it works fine. The `fetch()` line also works when entered in the devtools console, as long as the web page used has the same origin as the server script.

However, when I use the demo extension in a Windows environment, I get the error message "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch". In contrast, pasting the `fetch()` command into the console works and returns the server response, just as on the Mac. Is this a known issue with Chrome extensions, `fetch()` and Windows?

For testing the extension (can be downloaded from https://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/demo_ext.zip), navigate to https://mentimeter.com (I matched this site as it is my target in the original extension – you can enter another site in the manifest if you like). For testing the command in the devtools console, navigate to https://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/demo-list.txt

Mac: OS 12.4; Chrome 102.0.5005.61

Windows: OS 7 professional (emulated in Parallels Desktop 17.1.4 on my Mac); Chrome 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

***Demo extension***

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3, 
  "name": "demo_ext",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "demo",
  
  "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },    
"host_permissions":["https://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/*"],
 "content_scripts": [{
      "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.mentimeter.com/*"]
  }],
 
  "web_accessible_resources":[{"resources":[],
  "matches":["https://www.mentimeter.com/*"]}]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.command){
       case "runDemo":
        fetch("https://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/phptest.php").then(response => response.text()).then(data => sendResponse(data));
       break;
     };
    return true;
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ command: "runDemo" }, function (response) {
  console.log("demo data: " + response);
})
```

---

**server script**

```
<?php
  $id = date("U");
  echo $id;
?>
```

---

**command in console**

```
fetch("https://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/phptest.php").then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: The code is fully correct and it works as it should in Windows here. Try using `chrome://net-export` to debug connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jumps out to me in your setup is Win 7.

I looked at your site with a TLS test suite, it's using Letsencrypt - you should be aware that due to their chain of trust change, older OSes (especially if not fully updated, which can be an issue in a spun-up-for-quick-test VM) may trip on trusting the certificate.

You can test if that is the problem by opening https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org/ in your VM's Chrome and seeing if it is blocked as insecure.

If that is the case, you can work around the issue by adding the new ISRG X1 root certificate (self-signed) to your OS trust store from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

P.S. You can also quicky check if this is the issue by using non-HTTPS URL `http://oldpike.bxtrom.eu/mentiplus/phptest.php` for a quick test.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis; your suggestion seems to be correct. When I replaced the server script with another one hosted on a domain with an SSL certificate, my Windows extension made a successful connection. – Please note the added introduction in my original post: could it be such a common thing to have an "old" OS that the vast majority of extension users fail to connect due to the Letsencrypt issue?

Comment: If my hunch that you spun this VM as a fresh Win 7 install from a not-too-recent image is correct, your OS isn't in what would be a typical end-user state. Win 7 (and even WinXP!) do update their trust stores in typical configurations, see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/ It's *extremely* unlikely that this affects a big proportion of your users. I'd rather question the stats given to you by CWS rather than assume this situation is common "in the wild".

Comment: The CWS stats say about 600 users loaded the new version on June 20; the total number of successful connections logged on my server is 10, as of today – could the CWS stats be so much off? I guess there could be other issues, but I'll change the address of the server script to the domain with the SSL cert anyway and see if anything changes.

Comment: @danbae I have another hunch. Is it possible that the server is configured to allow caching of the responses upstream / is behind CDN like CloudFlare? Then you could see few requests unless you explicitly send headers that prevent caching..

Comment: The settings on my "Hosting Control Panel" do not indicate that any caching is taking place, and the Cloudflare option is not used. I have certainly not chosen any such settings myself. Sorry, I am really not good at these things – is there a way to determine if the configurations you listed are in use?

Comment: The discrepancy between the number of requests to the server and the CWS stats has been explained to me by the CWS support. Contrary to my expectation, no loading of pages matching the `"matches":` pattern in the `manifest.json` file is required to increment the CWS stats user count; it is sufficient that a user has the extension installed and has Chrome running, regardless of which pages are loaded. This document describes the user counting: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/updater/protocol_3_1.md#User-Counting

Comment: Returning to this subject, since the VM still hasn't learned to like Letsencrypt certificates. You outlined a workaround "adding the new ISRG X1 root certificate (self-signed) to your OS trust store". Could you please describe this procedure a little more in detail since I have been unable to locate the trust store and don't know how to add certificates to it. Also, the letsencrypt.org site offers certificates in various file formats, and I don't know which one is appropriate.

Comment: @danbae DER will do for Windows. Download the file, double-click to open its properties, choose "install certificate" and make sure you select "Trusted Root Certificates" store when installing.